# What is the following sql statement giving an error?

Tags: sql, oracle

I get an error when i try to do this using SQL. ftp.server is the key whose value i would like to change:

```
UPDATE OL_PREF SET ftp.server='dev.isinet.com'
```

Comment: is the field actually called "ftp.server"?

Comment: yes the field is called ftp.server

Comment: Your UPDATE statement (once you've fixed the column name problem) will update all rows in the table, since you have omitted a WHERE clause. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @Phoenix, if none of the answers so far are sufficient to solve your problem, I suggest you post the output of `describe ol_pref` and the specific error message you are getting when you try the update shown in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column name is really `ftp.server`, then the correct Oracle syntax for updating it should be

```
UPDATE OL_PREF SET "ftp.server" ='dev.isinet.com'
```

In Oracle, double quotes are the correct way to handle column names that have non-standard characters, including lower-case letters and the period.  Note that you must have the exact correct column name for this to work, including case.

You can verify the column name with:

```
SELECT column_name FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name='OL_PREF' ORDER BY column_name;
```

If what you really mean is that you have a table that stores key-value pairs, and that 'ftp.server' is a key, then you probably want an update like the one in Mark Wilkins' answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE OL_PREF SET [ftp.server]='dev.isinet.com'
```

or

```
UPDATE OL_PREF SET [ftp].[server]='dev.isinet.com'
```

if ftp is a schema and server is the fieldname.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put the column name in quotes.

You could use brackets, which have the same functionality as quotes.

```
UPDATE OL_PREF SET [ftp.server] ='dev.isinet.com'
```

Also, it's a good idea to use "two part naming", specifying the schema as well:

```
UPDATE dbo.OL_PREF SET [ftp.server] ='dev.isinet.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE OL_PREF 
SET ftp.server ='dev.isinet.com'
```

no '' for column names

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Update](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

'ftp.server' is in quotes. (and that should not be)

Comment: ftp.server looks like a field name, and should not be enclosed in quotes

Comment: I think he was saying that originally the OP used quotes around 'ftp.server'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the error ORA-00904 string : invalid identifier?

If so [read this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00904_string_invalid_identifier.htm)

I did a quick test on this

```
SQL> create table t_tab_1 ( tname varchar2(3), "ftp.service"  varchar2(20) );
```

Table created.

```
SQL> insert into t_tab_1(tname,"ftp.service") values('21','ftp://fila');
```

1 row created.

```
SQL> update t_tab_1 set "ftp.service"='fila.real.com';
```

1 row updated.

If there is more than I row in your table remember to use the where clause in your update statement.